# How to suppress the warning message for NaN values for groupings with only one observation when using the summarySE function in R?

Tags: r, shiny, nan, na, summary

I'm creating a dashboard that utilises the summarySE function. This is working as expected so far, but I've noticed that the console window produces error messages when using this function on a table using a grouping which contains at least one group with only one observation in it. (This causes SD, SE, and CI to fail.)

Is there a way to suppress error messages caused by this instance? This is not something I'm concerned about as I expect there to be some small groupings like that, but I don't want error messages to be produced unless I need to actually investigate something.

As an example...

```
summarySE(head(iris),measurevar='Sepal.Width', groupvars=('Petal.Length'))
```

Only one grouping (Petal.Length = 1.4) has more than one observation. NA is produced under the relevant stats for the other groups with only one observation. The above function gives the following output:

```
  Petal.Length N Sepal.Width       sd        se        ci
1          1.3 1    3.200000       NA        NA        NA
2          1.4 3    3.366667 0.321455 0.1855921 0.7985386
3          1.5 1    3.100000       NA        NA        NA
4          1.7 1    3.900000       NA        NA        NA
Warning message:
In qt(conf.interval/2 + 0.5, datac$N - 1) : NaNs produced
```

I know there is a na.rm argument which you can set to TRUE/FALSE to ignore NA values but this doesn't seem to do anything that I can notice in this case.

Does anyone know how to suppress this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the warning message this is due to `qt()` function giving `NaN` whenever degrees of freedom is 1.  You can use `suppressWarnings()` on `qt()` in your own copy of the function `summarySE`, as shown below.

```
summarySE <- function(data=NULL, measurevar, groupvars=NULL, na.rm=FALSE,
                      conf.interval=.95, .drop=TRUE) {
  library(plyr)
  
  # New version of length which can handle NA's: if na.rm==T, don't count them
  length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
    else       length(x)
  }
  
  # This does the summary. For each group's data frame, return a vector with
  # N, mean, and sd
  datac <- ddply(data, groupvars, .drop=.drop,
                 .fun = function(xx, col) {
                   c(N    = length2(xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     mean = mean   (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     sd   = sd     (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm)
                   )
                 },
                 measurevar
  )
  
  # Rename the "mean" column    
  #datac <- plyr::rename(datac, c("mean" = measurevar))
  names(datac)[names(datac) == 'mean'] <- measurevar
  
  datac$se <- datac$sd / sqrt(datac$N)  # Calculate standard error of the mean
  
  # Confidence interval multiplier for standard error
  # Calculate t-statistic for confidence interval: 
  # e.g., if conf.interval is .95, use .975 (above/below), and use df=N-1
  ciMult <- suppressWarnings(qt(conf.interval/2 + .5, datac$N-1))
  datac$ci <- datac$se * ciMult
  
  return(datac)
}

summarySE(head(iris),measurevar='Sepal.Width', groupvars='Petal.Length', na.rm=TRUE, .drop=TRUE)
```

Comment: Looks like that did the trick, thanks! Never thought about editing packaged functions, good to know that approach.